# subtracting element of an array from next elements

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array  i want to subtract the previous number from the next number after fixing the first number and want to replace  last number with zero

```
a=np.array([10,20,22,44])
```

expected output

```
np.array([10,10,2,0])
```

I tried with `np.diff` function but it misses the first number.Hope experts will suggest better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a custom output, so use a custom concatenation:

```
out = np.r_[a[0], np.diff(a[:-1]), 0]
```

Output: `array([10, 10,  2,  0])`

Comment: if i donot want to replace the last number with zero then how to do it

Comment: Then `np.r_[a[0], np.diff(a)]` or `np.diff(np.r_[0, a])`